# automatically running a bash script in the background

Tags: bash

I'm interested in finding out how I'm able to do the following, but automatically.

Right now I have a bash script that looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sass --watch htdocs/css/scss:htdocs/css --debug-info
```

Now, because I want to be able to run other command-line tasks at the same time as this script is running, I could just run it inside a new window, but I prefer to have it run as a background process, which I achieve by:

- Hitting [ctrl] + [Z]
- Running `bg`

Which lets me continue to use the command-line, while also seeing the output from the `sass` command.

I'm also able to use `jobs` to see what's running, and finally, `fg` to bring the background script to the forefront, and use [ctrl] + [c] to cancel out of it.

All of which is fine, but it's a bit long-winded - is there any way that I can edit the bash script so it will automatically run in the background, similar to what I've described above?

Thank you

Comment: use `&` at the end of comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ ./script &
           ^--- run script in background from the get-go
```

Comment: I am just curious about the explanation line. I have seen it at SO sometimes, how did you make it? manually? or there is some "magic" to learn? (I have seen mutli-lines as well)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to this , which I found useful is to write a function

`Foo(){
Do stuff
}`

and call the function and send it to the background

`Foo &`

All **within the script**, so you don't have to do

`script.sh &`

Instead, just invoking the script will send it to the background.